# CSS Padding Issue w/ submit button

Tags: html, css, forms

This is a dumb problem but I can't seem to set the padding on a submit button properly. No matter what I input for padding, the width and height of the button never changes. Here is the css:

```
.green_submit {
color: #fff;
background-color: #94c909;
border-right: 1px solid #6d9307;
border-bottom: 1px solid #6d9307;
border-left: none;
border-top: none;
padding: 25px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class='green_submit' value="Validate" />
```

Any obvious problems here? How can I manipulate the padding on a submit button?

Comment: Created jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnS3/. Works for me on IE8.

Comment: Works fine for me. You're going to have to post more of your HTML in order for anybody to help.  Also, you should use a DOM inspection tool like Firebug to see how the browser is interpreting your stylesheet.

Comment: ugg... that means there is a problem in one of my other style sheets. Thanks...

Comment: What browser do you use? Because it works on Chrome, IE, Firefox and Safari

Comment: It works for me too in IE8, FireFox and IE8(Compitibile)

Comment: The only thing you cannot style correctly in all browsers is submit buttons...the box-model is always different in every browser.  You just can't reliably do padding and height and line-height..just a fact of life

Comment: @MvanGeest your jsFiddle does not work on Chrome mobile/iOS

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try the `<button>` element, it allows better styling. Also this might be because the input element is an inline element. Adding display: inline-block; might help as well.

Comment: Were you suggesting the `<button>` element? That's not a very good idea, as it won't trigger `submit` without JavaScript.

Comment: The button element with type=submit should work fine, unless you refer to 'hit-enter-to-submit' functionality across various browsers. I know I've had issues with that in the past.

Comment: if people are working with frameworks, changing the HTML element is not always possible!